# Disable Source tab in Google Code

Tags: version-control, google-code

How to disable source tab in Google Code? I don't want any random users to look at my code.

Before you say that this can't be done, that Google Code is by default open source. [Someone managed to do it, somehow](http://code.google.com/p/cnprog/).

**Edit: Before you downvote me further, take a look at the link I provided. It's possible to do it, despite whatever you want to say. And I want to know how.**

Comment: They just turned off the Source tab in the Settings. http://img211.imageshack.us/img211/6857/picture1xce.png Doesn't stop people from getting to the code.

Comment: Three people have marked this offensive (hate speech, spam, or abuse)? WTF!?

Comment: The site that the Google code site links to is effectively a StackOverflow clone (site design and everything). This is spam.

Comment: @zacherates: I disagree. The way the question is worded makes it a legit question, not spam. If the question was "is this site better than SO" or something like that, it would be spam.

Comment: It's offensive because Google Code is for open source hosting, not private repositories.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Perhaps that makes the question misguided. It does not make it offensive. The offensive flag is for hate speech, spam, and abuse. This is none of those.

Comment: This is a valid question-- I believe that there are a lot of people who are dying to know how to do it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your GC page **Administer|Tabs** then check the hide checkbox next to Source. Your code will still be available via SVN though.

Answer (score 23):

> I don't want any random users to look at my code.

You can't prevent people from downloading the source code. Google's SVN repositories are open to anonymous browsing and checkout. For example, in the project you cited (the StackOverflow clone), notice that

```
svn checkout http://cnprog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ cnprog-read-only
```

works just fine for downloading the source.

If you don't want people looking at your source code, don't use a free public-hosting service. Setting up a local `svn` repository is very easy, in any case: **[here's](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.importing.html)** how you'd go about setting one up and adding stuff to it.

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of Google Code is that it is for open source. That means everyone is allowed to see it. If you don't want people looking at your code, use some closed source hosting site.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace tabs with Wiki pages (for example, to point to your GitHub repository), but you can't prevent access to the Google SVN server.